# Connecting to website via domain redirects to IP(no guides nor "fixes" helped)

Tags: django, nginx, dns, ip, digital-ocean

I am using GoDaddy domain and connectiong it to django+gunicorn+nginx droplet hosted on DigitalOcean.
After all tried configs of DO, nginx, etc., I'm still getting the same result.
When I'm trying to connect via domain, it changes it to IP address and proceeds...
Last nginx config I stopped on is:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name example.com www.example.com ip.ip.ip.ip;

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location /static/ {
    root /home/user/webapp;
}

location /media/ {
    root /home/user/webapp;
}

location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/user/webapp/webapp.sock;
}
}
```

Removing IP completely from nginx conf results in same behavior but instead of getting Django webpage I'm getting redirected to nginx default webpage and the domain is again changed to IP.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this statement

`location \homepage {
          rewrite ^ http://$host$request_uri? permanent;
 }`

Comment: As said if I remove ip from there completely, it just does the same thing, but displays nginx default webpage instead of Django websapp

Comment: I already figured it out, you can add it as answer and I'll mark it :)